# How to disable multi-repo in Visual Studio 17.6.2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After the latest update Visual Studio 2022 started offering me this new multi-repo feature.

I remember disabling it previously since I had issues with it then too. Since this is no longer a preview feature there's no toggle to disable it as I did in the previous patches.

I understand the premise of it, but for me it auto-detects the wrong repositories as related, and there is no way to unlink the repositories. I don't even know how it decides which repositories are supposed to be opened together since I do not opt-in at any point.

Does anyone know how to disable it in the latest versions or at least have it not automatically open multiple repositories, or remove repositories from the "active repositories" list?

PS: I know of the other question on SO, but that one relates to an older version of VS.

**Edit 1:**

There's nothing special about the directory structure. It detects some absolutely unrelated applications as being a multi-repo solution. The only thing they have in common is the company prefix.

```
C:
└── src
    ├── Acme.WebSite
    └── Acme.SomeApi
```

There are more solutions like these. Some open as multi-repo some as single repo. Couldn't figure out a correlation between the repos.

Edit 2:

Here's what the "Preview Features" tab looks like

[image]

Edit 3:

I ended up trying a lot of things, re-cloning the repositories, clearing VS caches, cleaning the registry, renaming directories, renaming repositories, etc.

None of this helped. As soon as I would clone some (unrelated) repositories under the same directory it automatically detected the repositories as a multi-repo solution and would load them on start. Weirdly enough it would do that only when opening solutions in some of the auto-detected repositories but not others.

The only thing that helped is creating additional nested hierarchies of directories for my repositories. Since I had around 50 repos in the same folder it took a while to move them around. And what's funnier it doesn't detect the actually related repositories.

Comment: If you gave a bit more information about how your repo looks like, what you get and what you expected, somebody could give you a hint on what to change to make the feature work correctly. From your description, you seem to have a very unusual repository layout.

Comment: @PMF there's nothing special just .NET websites and services all at the same level. Updated post.

Comment: @shingo as the title says VS 2022 (v17.6.2)

Comment: @AndreiIvascu That is to say, the version of Visual Studio you are using does not have the "Multi-repo Support .." option in Preview Features?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT yes the version I'm using (the latest) does not list the multi-repo feature as preview or any other feature that can be disabled, and I need it disabled or at least know how to opt-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently some solution files contained  relative paths that occasionally matched projects from neighboring repositories.

That's why solutions seemed to randomly be loaded together by VS.

Since everyone had the same directory structure, and projects were rarely changed the problem went unnoticed for a while, only to be uncovered by my annoyance this weird VS feature.