# Disable mult-repo support GIT in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I have a problem with multiple branches being open in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.3.

Previous versions, in the menu "Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features", there was a checkbox to disable this multiple branches feature.

But in version 17.6.3 this option does not exist any longer. Does anyone know how I can disable this feature in this version?

like this on version 17.4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUeyh.png)

I didn't find any solution for this problem yet

Comment: The problem is not Visual Studio showing you multiple branches. You have had multiple branches checked out since before that feature. You probably have a solution with projects from multiple repositories open. Please explain your problem properly.

Comment: I have a solution with 3 projects used like reference on my solutions, each of this project is a project on azure. so when I open the solution on visual studio each of this project is on multiple branch.

Comment: So where's the problem in that?

Comment: the problem is I like to disable that !
is very confusion to new development guys im my team work.

Comment: This is going nowhere with one comment every two days. Embrace the fact that working in multiple repos is what you're doing. You can hide that fact, but that will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Here is a similar post that I hope can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76404266/how-to-disable-multi-repo-in-visual-studio-17-6-2